# MyLocationOverlay doesn't appear

Tags: android, location

when I call this method the blue dot is not appearing on the map, until i send location from ddms,
then suddenly it appears.

```
    private void findMyLocation(final Location location){
    final MyLocationOverlay myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
    myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
    myLocationOverlay.enableCompass();
    final GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6),
            (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));
    controller.animateTo(point);
    controller.setCenter(point);
    mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay);
    mapView.postInvalidate();
}
```

how can i show that blue dot right after calling this method?
thanks a lot.

Comment: As CommonsWare says, how do you suggest it show your location before knowing your location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can i show that blue dot right after calling this method?

You can't.

`MyLocationOverlay`, as its name suggests, shows the user's location. If the device/emulator does not know the user's location, it cannot show it.

In the case of the device, it will not show the user's location until it has determined said location (e.g., GPS).

In the case of the emulator, it will not show the user's location until it has determined said location (e.g., DDMS).

Comment: Are you saying that implementing locationListener, particularly onLocationChanged will solve the problem on real device? (on emulator still doesnt appear)

Comment: @Varand Tin: The location dot *may* show up faster if you have already started getting GPS fixes. I have not tried that. I would think that would work, but I have been wrong about this sort of thing before... :-) With respect to the emulator, it will not matter, because you still need to pretend to be a GPS satellite via DDMS, and so the blue dot will still not appear until you have done so, AFAIK.